# How to turn on screen

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 (As Universal) and Windows Phone 8.0 (as Silverlight).

I was wonder is it possible to never screen light turn off in my application? For example in each media player, when you playing a video, the phone didn't turn off the screen. I'm not making a media player so please do not offer me for this.

Thanks

Comment: Main screen turn on.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942952/prevent-automatic-screen-lock-on-windows-phone-8

Comment: For *RunTime* - use [DisplayRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23653968/2681948).